# NoClassDefFoundError jakarta/servlet/http/HttpSessionContext after upgrade to spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

In my gradle base project I'm trying upgrade spring dependency from 2.7.6 to 3.0.1,

However I face issue `NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpSessionContext`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpSessionContext
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.newSessionHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.getSessionHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.relinkHandlers(ServletContextHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:228)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.<init>(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:28)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSessionContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

As I understand spring boot 3.0 use Servlet Api 6.0 which is not supported by Jetty and it requires downgrade Servlet API to 5.0.0
(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#jetty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this issue, you need to add to your `gradle.build` script
`ext['jakarta-servlet.version'] = '5.0.0'`

Comment: @Koedlt I would like to do so, but Stackoverflow shows me that I can do it only after 2 days

Comment: Ahh right, if you think of doing that whenever you're able to would be great! Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, and the previously suggested option was not working for everything. Either the service would start or all the tests (inc mockmvc) would succeed. But not everything. Setting `5.0.0` or `6.0.0` would only make one part to work... :-(

In the end, this setup has worked for all:

```
    ext {
        set("jakarta-servlet.version", '5.0.0')
    }
```

plus:

```
    testImplementation 
            'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:11.0.14',
            'jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0',
```